# How would I find the time-complexity of a recursive method in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I haven't been able to grasp the concept of complexity fully and I was wondering how I would be able to calculate it for method f(n) in this code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    r.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int n = r.nextInt(20) + 1;
    f(n);
  }

  private static void f(int n){
    if(n > 0){
      g(n);
      System.out.println();
      f(n-1);
    }
  }

  private static void g(int n){
    if(n > 0){
      System.out.print('X');
      g(n-1);
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that this is a recursive method which is what is confusing me. I see that every time the function f() is called, g() is is called, and run n times, and then f() calls itself as n-1 again until n=0. I don't know where to start Any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common technique for determining the runtime of recursive functions is to write out *recurrence relations* that describe the runtime as a quantity defined in terms of itself. Let's start with g. If we let c<sub>n</sub> denote the runtime of g(n), then we have

- c<sub>0</sub> = 1   (calling g(0) takes a constant amount of work)
- c<sub>n+1</sub> = c<sub>n</sub> + 1 (calling g(n) does a constant amount of its own work, then calls g(n-1)

We can look over a couple of values to c to see if we spot a pattern:

- c<sub>0</sub> = 1
- c<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>0</sub> + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
- c<sub>2</sub> = c<sub>1</sub> + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
- c<sub>3</sub> = c<sub>2</sub> + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4

Generally speaking, it looks like c<sub>n</sub> = n + 1. You can formalize this by using a proof by induction if you'd like, but for now we're going to take it on faith. This means that the runtime of g is O(n).

Now, let's let d<sub>n</sub> be the runtime of calling f(n). Notice that

- d<sub>0</sub> = 1 (calling f(0) does a constant amount of work)
- d<sub>n+1</sub> = d<sub>n</sub> + c<sub>n+1</sub> (calling f(n+1) calls g(n+1), requiring c<sub>n+1</sub> work, then calls f(n)

We can expand this out to see if we see a pattern.

- d<sub>0</sub> = 1
- d<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>0</sub> = 2 + 1
- d<sub>2</sub> = c<sub>2</sub> + d<sub>1</sub> = 3 + 2 + 1
- d<sub>3</sub> = c<sub>3</sub> + d<sub>2</sub> = 4 + 3 + 2 + 1

Generally, it looks like d<sub>n</sub> = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1. You can formalize this by induction if you'd like. This is a famous sum, and it works out to n(n+1) / 2. This quantity happens to be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), so the overall runtime is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 2):

First, calculate the number of times g() is called as a function of the initial argument n passed to f().  This gives you the amount of time taken by the function, as a multiple of the time it takes g() to execute, exclusive of recursion.

Then drop coefficients and lower order terms.  For example, if your result was 0.5n^2 + 0.5n, you would drop the 0.5n since it was a lower order term - not squared - leaving 0.5n^2, and you would drop the 0.5 coefficient, leaving n^2.  This would mean the function runs in O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 2):

While not a general strategy for analyzing recursion, your `f(n)` is essentially a loop running `g(k)` for values of `k` spanning 1 to n. So the run-time of `f(n)` is essentially the summation of run-times of  `g(n)`, `g(n-1)`, ..., `g(2)`, `g(1)`.

Since you already know the run-time of `g(k)` is essentially `k`, your ultimate run-time is a summation from 1 to n. If you know your summation formulas you'll know its order is O(n<sup>2</sup>).